# Python Pandas Kaufman Adaptive Moving Average (KAMA) --- Recursive Calculation in Pandas or Cython

Tags: python, pandas, cython

I am trying to create a function for the Kaufman Adaptive Moving Average (KAMA), in Python Pandas or using Cython  (I have already done this in R & Rcpp). Am having problems with the recursive calculation, filt1

```
filt1[i] =  ( filt1[i-1] + SC[i]*(price[i]-filt1[i-1]) )
```

I am expecting the KAMA Series should have
(i)  NA's to begin with, length of n=10
(ii) To start KAMA, for 2010-01-19 the raw mean of the price 1142.393, in this case the mean of the close's
(iii) Thereafter KAMA values from the recursive formulae filt1[i]

So:

```
KAMA
2010-01-04       NA
2010-01-05       NA
2010-01-06       NA
2010-01-07       NA
2010-01-08       NA
2010-01-11       NA
2010-01-12       NA  
2010-01-13       NA
2010-01-14       NA
2010-01-15       NA
2010-01-19 1142.393
2010-01-20 1142.367
2010-01-21 1142.244
2010-01-22 1140.212
2010-01-25 1138.683
2010-01-26 1136.517
```

To end with

```
2013-12-24 1791.114
2013-12-26 1802.816
2013-12-27 1814.759
2013-12-30 1822.844
2013-12-31 1830.523
```

I have made a start,

```
#%%
# Include this line for NEW WINDOW(S) for figures
%pylab qt4 

# start with getting some data to test on
import datetime
import tradingWithPython as twp # main toolkit functions
import tradingWithPython.lib.yahooFinance as yf # yahoo finance module   
import tradingWithPython.lib.backtest as backtest
from tradingWithPython.lib.extra import ProgressBar # import progress bar

#The python module (talib) that I will be using to calculate the technical 
#indicators is a wrapper around the open source TA-Lib. 
import talib
import numpy as np

import pandas.io.data as web  

import pandas.stats.moments

import pandas as pd
#pd.set_option('html', False) # how to display data - DEFAULT is True
#pd.set_option('display.height', int(1e7))
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', int(1e7))
#pd.set_option('display.max_columns', int(1e7))
pd.set_option('display.width', 3000)
#%%


#%%
def KAMA(x, n=10, pow1=2, pow2=30):
  ''' kama indicator '''    
  ''' accepts pandas dataframe of prices '''


  d['absDiffx'] = abs(x - x.shift(1) )  

  d['ER.num'] = ( x - x.shift(n) )
  d['ER.den'] = pandas.stats.moments.rolling_sum(d['absDiffx'],n)
  d['ER'] = d['ER.num'] / d['ER.den']

  d['SC'] = ( d['ER']*(2.0/(pow1+1)-2.0/(pow2+1.0))+2/(pow2+1.0) ) ** 2.0


  return d['SC']    
#%%



#%%
#Download data from yahoo finance
start = datetime.datetime(2010,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2013,12,31)
ticker = "^GSPC"
d=web.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo',start,end) 

d.info()
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#DatetimeIndex: 1006 entries, 2010-01-04 00:00:00 to 2013-12-31 00:00:00
#Data columns (total 6 columns):
#Open         1006 non-null float64
#High         1006 non-null float64
#Low          1006 non-null float64
#Close        1006 non-null float64
#Volume       1006 non-null int64
#Adj Close    1006 non-null float64


type(d)
#pandas.core.frame.DataFrame


d.head()
d.tail()
#%%



#%%
#calculate KAMA
#---------------
kama = KAMA(d.Close, n=10, pow1=2, pow2=30)

type(kama)
#pandas.core.frame.DataFrame


kama.head(100)
kama.tail(10)
#%%



#%%
df = pd.DataFrame({'price':d.Close, 'KAMA':KAMA(d.Close, n=10, pow1=2, pow2=30) })
df.plot(subplots=True)
#%%
```

How to do I calculate filt1[i] within Pandas or using Cython, with result as a pandas dataframe? Many Thanks.

Comment: It is not common practice in SO to rewrite answers that you're given to the working example that is specific to your case. If an answer was useful to you, you should rather accept it (with the tick). [I've seen you doing this regularly now]

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the replies. Works!

```
#%%
def KAMA(price, n=10, pow1=2, pow2=30):
    ''' kama indicator '''    
    ''' accepts pandas dataframe of prices '''

    absDiffx = abs(price - price.shift(1) )  

    ER_num = abs( price - price.shift(n) )
    ER_den = pandas.stats.moments.rolling_sum(absDiffx,n)
    ER = ER_num / ER_den

    sc = ( ER*(2.0/(pow1+1)-2.0/(pow2+1.0))+2/(pow2+1.0) ) ** 2.0


    answer = np.zeros(sc.size)
    N = len(answer)
    first_value = True

    for i in range(N):
        if sc[i] != sc[i]:
            answer[i] = np.nan
        else:
            if first_value:
                answer[i] = price[i]
                first_value = False
            else:
                answer[i] = answer[i-1] + sc[i] * (price[i] - answer[i-1])
    return answer
#%%


#%%
#calculate KAMA
#---------------
kama = KAMA(d.Close, n=10, pow1=2, pow2=30)
kama
#%%
```

Comment: Please advise me. This code is showing this error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'shift'

Comment: Hi, years past, if you still watch this answer, would you please explain, is it possible to rewrite the `range` part in this function with `pandas.ewm` API ? and how ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check that this actually gives you the answer you're expecting, but as a starting point, here's a pretty quick cython version of this.  Someone better at Cython that me may spot some obvious improvements.  A quick speed comparison:

```
In [448]: %timeit df['kama_python'] = filt_python(df['sc'].values, df['price'].values)
10 loops, best of 3: 22.5 ms per loop

In [449]: %timeit df['kama_cython'] = filt_cython(df['sc'].values, df['price'].values)
1000 loops, best of 3: 300 µs per loop
```

In terms of writing this, I started with a pure python version (see below), and kept adding type annotations (good example in the pandas [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html)) until it was fast.  Thanks to @Jeff for pointing the correct way the check np.nan  (`v != v`).

```
%%cython

cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cpdef np.ndarray[double] filt_cython(np.ndarray[double] sc, np.ndarray[double] price):
    cdef np.ndarray[double] answer = np.zeros(sc.size)
    cdef int N = len(answer)
    cdef int i
    first_value = True    

    for i in range(N):
        if sc[i] != sc[i]:
            answer[i] = np.nan
        else:
            if first_value:
                answer[i] = price[i]
                first_value = False
            else:
                answer[i] = answer[i-1] + sc[i] * (price[i] - answer[i-1])
    return answer
```

Here's the pure python version I started with.

```
def filt_python(sc, price):
    answer = np.zeros(sc.size)
    N = len(answer)
    first_value = True

    for i in range(N):
        if i == 0 or pd.isnull(sc[i]):
            answer[i] = np.nan
        else:
            if first_value:
                answer[i] = price[i]
                first_value = False
            else:
                answer[i] = answer[i-1] + sc[i] * (price[i] - answer[i-1])
    return answer
```

Comment: comparing a ``value==np.nan`` always fails, instead do ``v != v`` (means its a ``np.nan`` in a quick way if you know its a float)

Comment: FYI this almost solves https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4567 (just needs to be a bit more general)

Answer (score 0):

you can use talib.KAMA but it doesn't correctly Comparision with tradingview.

```
import talib 
import pandas as pd

def calc_kama(src, length, fastend=0.666, slowend=0.0645):
    diff = abs(src-np.roll(src,1))
    noise = talib.SUM(diff, length)
    noise= np.where(np.isnan(noise),1,noise)
    signal = talib.MOM(src,length)
    signal  = np.where(np.isnan(signal),0,signal)
    efratio = np.where((noise!=0) , (signal/noise), 1)
    efratio = np.round(efratio,2)
    smoothing_constant = pow(efratio*(fastend-slowend)+slowend,2)
    smoothing_constant = pd.Series(smoothing_constant)

    sma = pd.Series(src.rolling(length).mean(), name="SMA")
    kama = []
    for smooth, sma_param, price in zip(
        smoothing_constant.iteritems(), sma.shift().iteritems(), src.iteritems()
    ):
        try:
            kama.append(kama[-1] + smooth[1] * (price[1] - kama[-1]))
        except (IndexError, TypeError):
            if pd.notnull(sma_param[1]):
                kama.append(sma_param[1] + smooth[1] * (price[1] - sma_param[1]))
            else:
                kama.append(None)
    ## apply the kama list to existing index
    kama_s = pd.Series(kama, index=sma.index, name=df_column_name).round(2)
    return kama_s

######################
```