# Compile error in Kaufman’s Adaptive Moving Average python code

Tags: python

I want to use Kaufman’s Adaptive Moving Average (KAMA) for my Master’s thesis. I got the code from [Python Pandas Kaufman Adaptive Moving Average (KAMA) --- Recursive Calculation in Pandas or Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340935/python-pandas-kaufman-adaptive-moving-average-kama-recursive-calculation-i)
However, I cannot run this code because it is showing these errors:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'shift'
>
> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'stats'

Please help me to solve the problem.

```
#%%
import numpy as np
import pandas


def KAMA(price, n=10, pow1=2, pow2=30):
    ''' kama indicator '''
    ''' accepts pandas dataframe of prices '''

    absDiffx = abs(price - price.shift(1) ) 

    ER_num = abs( price - price.shift(n) )
    ER_den = pandas.stats.moments.rolling_sum(absDiffx,n)
    ER = ER_num / ER_den

    sc = ( ER*(2.0/(pow1+1)-2.0/(pow2+1.0))+2/(pow2+1.0) ) ** 2.0


    answer = np.zeros(sc.size)
    N = len(answer)
    first_value = True

    for i in range(N):
        if sc[i] != sc[i]:
            answer[i] = np.nan
        else:
            if first_value:
                answer[i] = price[i]
                first_value = False
            else:
                answer[i] = answer[i-1] + sc[i] * (price[i] - answer[i-1])
    return answer
#%%


marray = np.arange(20)
KAMA(marray)
```

Comment: One of the reason is python and panda version mismatch. I am using python 3 and panda 0.25.0.

Answer (score 0):

stats.moments.rolling_sum is no longer available in the latest version of pandas. You can do the same thing using the `rolling` method.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html

Comment: Showing this error:   File "E:/25 december/test7.py", line 13, in KAMA
    ER_den = pandas.stats.moments.rolling(absDiffx,n)
  File "E:\25 december\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 214, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module 'pandas' has no attribute '{}'".format(name))
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'stats'